# Enable overflow in native-base cards

Tags: css, react-native, native-base

I have a component in a website that looks like this:

[Regular card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lhN9.png)

It's basically a div with an image inside it, but the image has a `margin-top` of -50 so that it overflows off the card.

I would like to accomplish the same thing with react-native and native-base. Here is the relevant code:

```
    render() {
       return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Card>
                <CardItem style={{ marginTop: -50, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: this.state.band.imageComponent.link }} />
                </CardItem>
            </Card>
         </View>
       )
    }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 150
   },
   image: {
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
   )
```

And the result looks like this:
[React-native card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2UTT.png)

As you can see, the picture is cutoff at the top. How can I keep the image overflow and have it overlay the card like in my first image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overflow is not supported in Android. There are lots of open issues for that. Check some of them [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6802) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3198).

Here's an [npm package](https://github.com/entria/react-native-view-overflow) that apparently solves that issue that you could try.

Otherwise you can use a workaround for that I found on this [medium post](https://medium.com/companydev/react-native-android-doesnt-render-overflow-styles-95e69154ebed).

According to your image you have to wrap your image and the container inside another `View` as siblings and then position them absolutely.

Here's the code that I tweaked a little bit from that [post](https://medium.com/companydev/react-native-android-doesnt-render-overflow-styles-95e69154ebed). You can replace the `View` according to your `Card` and `CardItem` styles.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.cardSection1}>
    <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: 'https://imgplaceholder.com/420x320/ff7f7f/333333/fa-image' }} />
  </View>
  <View style={styles.cardSection2}>
  </View>
</View>

const styles = {
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: 'grey',
   alignItems: 'center'
  },
  image: {
   width: 150,
   height: 150,
  },
  cardSection1: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 50 / 2,
    zIndex: 2,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    shadowRadius: 10,
    elevation: 7,
  },
  cardSection2: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 25,
    width: 300,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    zIndex: 1,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    shadowRadius: 10,
    elevation: 5,
  }
}
```

This is the output that I got.

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

```js
//import liraries
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet,TextInput,Dimensions,Image } from 'react-native';
import ButtonRoundBorder from '../components/ButtonRoundBorder';


const window = Dimensions.get('window')
// create a component
class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image style={{width:window.width,height:window.height,position:'absolute'}} source={require('../images/bg2.jpeg')}/>
                <View  style={styles.overlayImageStyle} >
                    <Image style={{flex:1,borderRadius:80}} resizeMode={'contain'} source={require('../images/profile.jpg')} />
                </View>
                <View   style={styles.cardStyle}>
                    <View style={styles.insideCard}>
                        <Text style={{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:20,alignSelf:'center'}}>Login</Text>
                        <TextInput style={[styles.textInputStyle,{marginTop:30}]} underlineColorAndroid='#000000' placeholder='Enter Email' />
                        <TextInput style={[styles.textInputStyle,{marginTop:20}]} underlineColorAndroid='#000000'  placeholder='Enter Password' />
                        <ButtonRoundBorder style={{marginTop:40}} title='Login'/>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
            
        );
    }   
}                               


const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 

    container:{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
    overlayImageStyle:{
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'absolute',
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        borderRadius: 100/2,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        top:50,
        shadowColor: '#000', 
        // position: 'absolute',row
        // shadowOpacity: 0.2, 
        // shadowRadius: 10,
        elevation: 7,
    },
    cardStyle:{
        // alignItems: 'center',
        // justifyContent: 'center',
        // position: 'absolute',
        top: 80,
        width: window.width - 40,
        height: window.height - 200,
        borderRadius: 8,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        // backgroundColor: '#7E57C2',
        shadowColor: '#000',
        elevation: 5,
    },
    insideCard:{
        top: 80,
        alignContent: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',   
        flexDirection:'column',
        
    },
    textInputStyle:{
        width:300,
        height:40,
        alignSelf:'center',
        
    }

});

//make this component available to the app
export default Login;
```

[here is the link for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E1Xr.png)

Comment: Please. can you explain why this is the answer?

Comment: I created 2 views and made one overlap the other using position: ' absolute'. Used this method since its lot more easier than using native base and I failed when trying to do this with native base.